# Скрипт поднять объявления

Tags: php

Есть доска объявлений, в ней есть VIP-статус. При присвоении VIP-статуса прикрепляется `class="topmess ads"`. Какой написать php-код, чтобы этот скрипт можно было запустить через `CRON`. Команда "поднять объявление". Может, дадите пару советов?

Comment: Любой ПХП скрипт запускается из командной строки 'php script/path/script. name.php'. Эта команда и добавляется в Крон.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала я бы распределил выдачу из БД, наверняка это реально ( к примеру на 10 обычных 3 vip). Дальше средствами php  присваивал бы класс "topmess ads" и соответственно ставил выше других при формировании html-страницы. Тут даже cron не нужен. Достаточно прописать условие проверки оплаченного vip статуса.  Очередь показов vip объявлений - для равномерного распределения показов - отсортировать по наименьшим показам, выбрать нужное число объявлений, обновить счётчик показов соответственно.